# Bind property from element in ItemsSource to Label Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've created own UserControl. This Control has own property `ItemsSource` of type `Dictionary<string, object>`. Key - it's Title of element in collection that I bind to ItemsSource.

Can I have access to any property of `ItemsSource` without adding it's value separately to `ItemsSource` (don't transform to `List<Tuple<string, string, object>>`)

---

```
public class Book
{
   public int Id{get;set}
   public string Title{get;set;}
   public string Description{get;set;}
}

var list = new List<Book>(){//initializing};
userControl.ItemsSource = list.ToDictionary(i => i.Title, i => i);
```

So I want to access `Description` if I have just `ItemsSource`. Is it possible?

---

My UserControl is  the same as written here [MultipleComboBox](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/multi-select-combobox-in-wpf/)

and I bind ItemsSource like this :

```
<controls:MultiSelectComboBox SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedBooks, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="Books" DefaultText="Category" ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"/>
```

---

I solution that I can imagine - add property to class Node, which will be initialized with Value property of ItemsSource. After it bind like Value.Description.

public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

```
    private string _title;
    private object _value;
    private bool _isSelected;
    #region ctor
    public Node(string title, object value)
    {
        Title = title;
        Value = value;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _title;
        }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

But is it good solution? From performance side. Thanks

Comment: can't you just bind to `Value.Description`?

Comment: @AntiHeadshot, nope... Value is not recognizable

Comment: could you add a XAML snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `ItemTemplate`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Description}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Key and Value doesn't return anything

Comment: @demo Books is of type `Dictionary<string,Book>`, do you see any binding errors in your output?

Comment: @demo so there are no lines like `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:` in your output window?

Comment: @demo I downloaded the demo files and tried to bind to the `SelectedItems`, it seems the Multiselect isn't updating the Property corectly.